# RecyclerView findViewHolder null for off-screen items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[first time asker and first time android coder so I apologize if I do something wrong]

I'm trying to change the value inside of an itemview on my recycler. However, if that itemview happens to be offscreen, the findViewBy[layout,adapter,or id] comes up null.

```
public void setUserActive(UserListAdapter adapter, RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(adapter.getItemId(position));
    TextView txtActive = (TextView) vh.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_isActive);
    txtActive.setText("Active");
    UserListAdapter.ViewHolder inactivevh = (UserListAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(adapter.getItemId(adapter.getActiveUserPosition()));
    TextView txtInActive = (TextView) inactivevh.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_isActive);
    txtInActive.setText("");
    adapter.setActiveUserPosition(position);
}
```

I've tried a few different ways, from using

```
  UserListAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (UserListAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(position);
```

or

```
UserListAdapter.ViewHolder inactivevh = (UserListAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
```

and they all fail when the view that should be inactivevh is off screen.

I've set the adapter to hasStableIDs = true
notifydatasetchanged doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Cache your views in the view holder, that's what they're for. So you call findViewById only once during their creation. http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example#26-implementingviewholderpattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an item is on screen (laid out) you can get its view holder conveniently using methods you described. **If an item is not on screen it will get updated as soon as it gets scrolled in via `onBindViewHolder`.** If it doesn't get scrolled in, it's not presented to user ergo any attempt to update it is a waste of processing power (apart from being impossible because the item doesn't have a view holder assigned).

Meaning: Implement your adapter in such way that `onBindViewHolder` is able to pull up-to-date data. Looks like you're all set up and can use this:

```
public void setUserActive(UserListAdapter adapter, RecyclerView recyclerView, int position) {
    // Retrieve the old active user ID so we can mark him deactivated.
    final int oldUserActivePosition = adapter.getActiveUserPosition();

    // Setup the adapter with current data.
    adapter.setActiveUserPosition(position);

    // Do NOT use stable IDs and this method. It just doesn't work as expected.
    // recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(adapter.getItemId(position));

    // Activate new user.
    UserListAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (UserListAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    if (holder == null) {
        // The item is off screen, no need to update it yet.
    } else {
        // Update the on screen item. The logic is already implemented in the adapter.
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }

    // Deactivate previous user.
    holder = (UserListAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(oldUserActivePosition);
    if (holder != null) {
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, oldUserActivePosition);
    }
}
```

Simplify the if-else block in your code of course.

#### EDIT:

I just realized how unnecessarily complicated the original solution is. As long as the adapter can react to all events you need in `onBindViewHolder` and the binding is realtively easy this will suffice:

```
public void setActiveUserPosition(int position) {
    if (mActiveUserPosition != position) {
        int oldPosition = mActiveUserPosition;
        mActiveUserPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(oldPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

All you need to call now is `adapter.setActiveUserPosition(position);` which renders `setUserActive` method obsolete.

Comment: Thanks this helped tremendously, both in execution and in understanding. It worked almost perfectly- it seems that maybe in my test case the off-screen objects WERE cached, so I had to 'adapter.notifyItemChanged(oldUserActivePosition);' and it popped right up. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, there is an easier way - check the alternative solution, it will probably be applicable in your case. No need to manually lookup holders.

Comment: Yup! and that was where my execution and understanding came in. I was understanding that the adapter picked up the data model, used it, and discarded it.. not that it could go back and reference it (like, you know, a DATA MODEL) -- once I realized that I moved the brunt of my code from the recycler to the adapter/model, and poof!

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec  I think I am having a similar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531900/android-how-to-fix-recyclerview-onbindviewholder.  I added an ELSE statement but am still getting an error.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to fix.

Comment: notifyItemChanged(position) with logic for the view visibility in onBindviewholder is the solution that works for me !